# Transfer from MS Access to SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, ms-access

We would like to transfer data from a MS Access database to SQLite. Unfortunately, SQlite does not support the whole range of functions provided by Access.

`ALTER TABLE Move DROP CONSTRAINT MoveEnum`

`ALTER TABLE IG_MDB_VERSION DROP COLUMN POOLART`

Can anyone give us a replacement in SQLite which realizes the above two SQL statements. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Handle your changes in MS Access before transferring to SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are now able to link to the sqlite  database from Access, and you can edit data with the linked tables from Access?

Then to execute your above sqlLite commands from Access?

Simply create + use what are called pass-though queries from Access. This will allow you to send/execute any valid sqlite commands from Access - including your example(s) in your question.

However before you attempt to use pass-though queries, you want to ensure that you can create linked tables from Access, and those linked tables allow you to edit data (say by clicking on a linked table in Access to sqlite, and that editing etc. works just  fine from Access.